# Searching array on multiple indexes

Tags: php

Given either of the following arrays (they are derived from JSON, and either can be created using `json_decode()`), how can I find the first key of the parent array for a given `x` and `y` value without manually iterating over the array?  For instance, given x=1 and y=3, return 1.  Ultimately, I wish to delete it, but finding it is the first step.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [x] => 1
            [y] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [x] => 1
            [y] => 3
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [x] => 2
            [y] => 2
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [x] => 4
            [y] => 2
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [x] => 1
            [y] => 4
        )

)
```

.

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [x] => 1
            [y] => 2
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [x] => 1
            [y] => 3
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [x] => 2
            [y] => 2
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [x] => 4
            [y] => 2
        )

    [4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [x] => 1
            [y] => 4
        )

)
```

Comment: Try [array_filter()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

Comment: @jedifans.  `array_filter()` returns the filtered array.  How would this help?

Comment: Where the keys are the indexes you require. Of course you can filter out those values instead, meaning you won't require a delete step.

Comment: @user1032531 You just filter out the array element where x and y matches

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`array_search`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) will do exactly that according to the documentation:

> Searches the array for a given value and returns the first corresponding key if successful

```
$data = [["x" => 1, "y" => 2], 
         ["x" => 1, "y" => 3], 
         ["x" => 2, "y" => 2],
         ["x" => 4, "y" => 2]];
$result = array_search(["x" => 2, "y" => 2], $data);
echo $result;
```

Output:

```
2
```

Comment: Wow, I never knew `array_search()` could accept an array!

Comment: @user1032531 An array is a value same as a string. So array_search just searches for a value in an array, which in your case is an array.

Comment: Good explanation.  Thanks.  Know why `array_search([2, 2], json_decode('[{"x":1,"y":2},{"x":1,"y":3},{"x":2,"y":2},{"x":4,"y":2},{"x":1,"y":4}]',true))` returns `false`?

Comment: @user1032531 One hint: keys! :)

Comment: @user1032531, It is false in that case, because an indexed array is not the same as an associative array with lettered keys. Rizier123 oversimplifies it: PHP really does a recursive match. You could find things like `[2, [5 => "A"]]` in an array. But both keys and values must match at all nested levels.

Comment: @trincot Simplifying it like this just offers itself to explain it easy :P

Comment: So, will `array_search` not work for my application given the initial data I described in the original post?

Comment: It will work for the data you posted in the question but you'd need to search for something like `["x" => 1, "y" => 3]`. I updated the example code in my answer to better match your data.

Comment: Ah, that works.  So, PHP is just searching for the string makeup of the array.  Gotcha!  PS.  I am pretty sure the original data is the same as that in the comment.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to search for a value in an array without iterating over the array, unfortunately. The time complexity is still `O(n)` because you are looking for a value inside the array, whereas the cost of finding a key is always `O(1)` in a PHP array, because it's a hash lookup. Any function you use in PHP to inspect array values will still have a cost of `O(n)`.

```
function getKey($x, $y, $arr)  {

    foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
        if ($x === $value["x"] && $y === $value["y"]) {
            return $key;
        }
    }

}
```

You could also write this function more generally as...

```
function getKey($needle, $haystack)  {

    foreach($haystack $key => $value) {
        if ($needle === $value) {
            return $key;
        }
    }

}
```

Which does the same thing as `array_search($needle, $haystack, true)`. However, the distinction is that `["y" => 1, "x" => 3] !== ["x" => 3, "y" => 1]` in PHP. So whereas the more specific function will always work as expected. The more general function has the edge case of caring about order in value.

Of course it's important to note that you may not *always* care about [strict comparison](http://php.net/types.comparisons), in which case `array_search` may work just fine for your needs.

Comment: But isn't `array_search()` doing it in a more efficient lower language?

Comment: They do the same thing. Whether or not one is more efficient than the other remains to be seen and is probably negligible anyway. I would be more concerned with correctness over efficiency. The performance differences here are moot. Doing the wrong thing *really fast* is worse than doing the right thing slightly slower.

Comment: I agree that it is negligible, however, "if" a single function can do it, it should probably be used.  Also, always like to learn new ways to do something.  Thanks

Comment: Well, that was exactly my point. Does `array_search` actually do what you want? It might. Note the distinction of the edge cases in the answer. Sometimes a general function doesn't always meet your specific needs. That's what you need to consider first, not the performance. Performance is **always** the last thing to consider. Correctness is **always** the first thing to consider.